# Inventories of iPods for different countries

Tags: c++, homework

We were given two countries, namely Brazil and Argentina. Both had one inventory each with 100 iPods in them. The cost of an iPod in Brazil was 100/unit and in Argentina it was 50/unit. But to get iPods form Argentina, you also had to pay 400/10units. Now they give us some number and we had to find out which purchase would be cheaper.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
class country
{
  public:
    int name;
    int items,unit;
    float cost,price;

  public:
    country();
    void purchase(std::string,int);
    void setData(int,int,float,float, int);
};
country::country()
{
}
void country::setData(int name,int items,float cost,float price,int unit)
{
  name=name;
  items=items;
  cost=cost;
  price=price;
  unit=unit;
}
void country::purchase(std::string a, int b)
{
  float custCost=0;
  std::cout<<a;
  cout<<"item"<<name;
  if(b<=items)
  {
    items=items-b;
    custCost=cost*b;
    cout<<name<<":"<<items<<":"<< custCost;
  }

}
int main()
{
  country t[2];
  t[0].setData(0,100,100,0,0);
  t[1].setData(1,100,50,400,20);
  std::string a;
  int b,con;
  cout<<"enter the country";
  std::cin>>a;
  cout<<"enter the items needed";
  cin>>b;
  if(a=="brazil")
    con=0;
  else con=1;
  t[con].purchase(a,b);

  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

It works but I am not totally satisfied with my design as I feel it's too cumbersome. Specifically, if I change the price etc., code changes have to be made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code doesn't seem to meet your specifications, but since you claim it works we'll ignore that.

blufox's suggestions are good. Here are a few more:

- Don't store currency as floats. Wrap it in a money class.
- You don't seem to use the price or unit fields in your country class, so I'd chuck 'em. If you want to keep them, you have to do something about you parameters list for setData. Try [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface):

  ```
  brazil.setName(0).setItems(100).setCost(100.00).setPrice(0.00).setUnits(0);
  ```
- SLVNAHTR (Single Letter Variable Names Are Hard To Read)
- `const int NUMBER_OF_WAYS_MAGIC_NUMBERS_SUCK = 800;`
  `const std::string CONSTANTS("are better");`
- There really should be some error checking for your input. `boost::lexical_cast` is good, or if Boost is not an option, try:

  ```
  template <typename InputType>
  InputType getValidatedInput(const std::string& prompt=std::string())
  {
      std::cout << prompt;

      while (true)
      {
          std::string input;
          std::getline(std::cin, input);

          std::istringstream converter(input);
          InputType result;
          converter >> result;

          if (converter.fail())
          {
              std::cout << "Invalid input. Try again: ";
              continue;
          }

          char junk;
          converter >> junk;

          if (converter.fail())
          {
              return result;
          }

          std::cout << "Extra character found: " << junk ". Try again: ";
      }
  }
  ```

  Also add extra validation to ensure that the country entered is either Brazil or Argentina (and not Alaska). You might want to make a menu, so the user knows their options.
- Declaring your instance variables `public` might have been a typo. You want them to be `private`.

Answer (score 4):

Before looking at your design, a few trivial points that you can correct,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
```

- Avoid c style header usage. Instead use the c++ header style, and namespaces.
- Instead of `conio.h/getch()` is not really portable. Avoid it.
- Your `setData` method should really be the constructor. Using setData to populate the structure is a `c` habit. Also be sure to use the member initializers for construction.

You really want to keep the members private

```
class country {
  private:
    int name;
    int items,unit;
    float cost,price;

    bool try_purchase(std::string,int);

  public:
    country(int,int,float,float, int);
    void do_purchace(std::string a);
};
country::country(int name,int items,float cost,float price,int unit)
          :name(name),items(items),cost(cost),price(price){}

// false indicates that the purchase failed.
bool country::try_purchase(std::string a, int b) {
  if(b > items) return false;
  items = items - b;
  return true;
}
void country::do_purchace(std::string a) {
  int b;
  std::cout<<"enter the items needed: ";
  std::cin>>b;
  if (try_purchase(a,b)) 
    std::cout<<name<<":"<<items<<":"<<cost * b<<std::endl;
}
int main()
{
  country t[] = {country(0,100,100,0,0), country(1,100,50,400,20)};
  std::string a;
  std::cout<<"enter the country: ";
  std::cin>>a;
  int con = (a=="brazil") ? 0 : 1;
  t[con].do_purchace(a);
}
```

Avoid incorporating io statements with your logic. Refactor `purchase` so that logic is separated to another method.

Regarding your assertion that code changes have to be made if you change price, I do not see why. You can read the information to construct a country from a file and thus avoid hard coding it in the main file. However, this does not change the design as a whole.

Comment: +1 but I don’t find `purchase` and `do_purchase` clear. `purchase` should be something along the lines of `try_purchase` to indicate the possibility of error (and explain the return value). And I probably wouldn’t make `do_purchase` a member function.

Comment: @KonradRudolph agree on the naming. I thought about the second point while implementing. I added do_purchase as a member function as it requires access to intimate details of country. The other option would be to make it a friend, but that would have the same level of coupling. Did you mean to write accessors for item and name, and make do_purchase a normal function?

Comment: No, I didn’t mean writing accessors (I prefer to avoid them), I overlooked that it used private data (stupid, I know).